# Derivative of Constant times norm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Compute:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W} \Vert c \times W^{T} \Vert
$$
where c $\in$ $R^{1 \times n}$, i.e. a vector independent of W and W $\in$ $R^{n \times n}$, and the norm is a Frobenius norm.

Comment: What's $c\times A$?

Comment: What is A here?

Comment: Matrix like $W$.

Comment: c x W is basically a nxn matrix.

Comment: I take your last answer as a non-unpolite suggestion that this conversation won't become interesting. Farewell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a row vector, let $c$ be a column vector.

Find the differential, then the gradient of the function as 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi^2 &= \|Wc\|^2 = Wc:Wc \cr
 2\phi\,d\phi &= 2Wc:dW\,c \cr
 d\phi &= \frac{1}{\phi}Wcc^T:dW \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W}
 &= \frac{1}{\phi}Wcc^T= \frac{Wcc^T}{\|Wc\|} \cr
}$$
In some of the steps above, a colon was used to denote the trace/Frobnius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
$$\eqalign{}$$
$$\eqalign{}$$
$$\eqalign{}$$